# What's the difference between Enzyme simulation in shallow and mount wrappers?

Tags: reactjs, testing, rendering, simulation, enzyme

Here's my component:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 'foo'
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          id="foo"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my test:

```
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';

it('fires onChange', () => {
  let wrapper = mount(<App />);

  wrapper.find('#foo').simulate('change', {currentTarget: {value: 'bar'}});

  expect(wrapper.state().value).toBe('bar');
  expect(wrapper.find('#foo').props().value).toBe('bar');
});
```

The test presently fails:

```
Expected value to be (using ===):
  "bar"
Received:
  "foo"
```

But if I change `mount` to `shallow`, it passes. I'm not entirely sure why, and I'd like to know if there are any other practical differences between shallow and mount rendering.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913

Comment: I've read that Gist multiple times, but it makes no reference to Enzyme's simulate functions. In this particular case, I'm guessing that the test fails because setState is an asynchronous function, and so the assertions are tested before the state is set...?

Comment: Shallow wrapper renders dom of your current component whereas mount renders the dom of your current component with their children components.

Answer (score 1):

For fixing the test, you can try:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

it('fires onChange', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />).find('#foo');

  expect(wrapper.props().value).toBe('foo');

  wrapper.props().onChange({ currentTarget: { value: 'bar' } });

  expect(wrapper.props().value).toBe('bar');
});
```

For clarification on difference between Shallow, Mount and render from enzyme

**Shallow**

Real unit test (isolation, no children render)

**Simple shallow**

Calls:

- constructor
- render

**Shallow + setProps**

Calls:

- componentWillReceiveProps
- shouldComponentUpdate
- componentWillUpdate
- render

**Shallow + unmount**

Calls:

- componentWillUnmount

**Mount**

The only way to test componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. Full rendering including child components. Requires a DOM (jsdom, domino). More constly in execution time. If react is included before JSDOM, it can require some tricks:

`require('fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment').canUseDOM = true;

**Simple mount**

Calls:

- constructor
- render
- componentDidMount

**Mount + setProps**

Calls:

- componentWillReceiveProps
- shouldComponentUpdate
- componentWillUpdate
- render
- componentDidUpdate

**Mount + unmount**

Calls:

- componentWillUnmount

**Render**

only calls render but renders all children.

So my rule of thumbs is:

- Always begin with shallow
- If componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate should be tested, use
  mount
- If you want to test component lifecycle and children behavior, use
  mount
- If you want to test children rendering with less overhead than mount
  and you are not interested in lifecycle methods, use render

There seems to be a very tiny use case for render. I like it because it seems snappier than requiring jsdom but as @ljharb said, we cannot really test React internals with this.

I wonder if it would be possible to emulate lifecycle methods with the render method just like shallow ? I would really appreciate if you could give me the use cases you have for render internally or what use cases you have seen in the wild.

I'm also curious to know why shallow does not call componentDidUpdate.

Kudos goes to https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913 and https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/465#issuecomment-227697726 this is basically a copy of the comment from the issue